# Google maps unable to the load url

Tags: android, google-maps

I try send a url to maps but the application show a toast "Unable to load the url". Have a suggestion to be posible be it?

follow code:

```
EditText edit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.enter);
String map = edit.getText().toString();
Uri location = Uri.parse("geo:" + map);
Intent mapIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, location);
startActivity(mapIntent);
```

Comment: Look like the contents of your EditText is not consistent with the spec

Comment: i don't understand your answer

Comment: Your code is perfect and you say the URL is bad. Since the URL is built dynamically ("geo:"+map), it means the contents of map must be bad. You should log them and see if they are consistent with the spec

Comment: i understand... are you a code solution for this?

Comment: No code to change, just write the correct thing in your edittext. For example write    48.7,3.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution by Philipe works. only use the georeferences in `EditText`, like 12,48.